# Attribute values for product variations

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, format, product, product-variations

I'm facing a big problem with product variations and their attributes in woocommerce. I'm trying to display a table with each attribute for each availabe product variation. But Woocommerce saves the attributes in post meta complete in lowercase, replaces slashes and german special characters like ü,ö,ä etc. I get the attributes with  `$variation->get_variation_attributes()`.

I've searched the database for the save values you can see for example in the dropdown in the admin panel, but they are saved like this without a link to the variation they are assigned to:

```
a:5:{s:10:"bestell-nr";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Bestell-Nr.";s:5:"value";s:9:"1 | 2 | and so on...
```

How can I get the attributes in their correct format to display?

Answer (score 17):

Actually product attributes are actually terms in custom taxonomies, so you just need to get the terms in that particular taxonomy. All attribute taxonomies are prefaced with 'pa_'. So a size attribute would be a 'pa_size' taxonomy. And the variation ID is the post ID for a variation.

But depending on how you want to display it, WooCommerce has a built-in function for displaying all a variation's attributes:

The following will display a definition list of all of a variations attributes.

```
echo wc_get_formatted_variation( $product->get_variation_attributes() );
```

And passing a second parameter of `true` will display a flat list:

```
echo wc_get_formatted_variation( $product->get_variation_attributes(), true );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried to get the attributes with get the terms, but the problem i'm facing is that they are wrong formated. It is all lowercase and special characters are replaced.

Comment: If you know the taxonomy's ID you can [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) that way too. Can you edit your question to explain what format you need them in / why `wc_get_formatted_variation()` won't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the snippet @helgatheviking, I didn't know about the wc_get_formatted_variation() func'

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work for me. Hope this helps.

```
$post = get_post();
$id =  $post->ID;
$product_variations = new WC_Product_Variable( $id );
$product_variations = $product_variations->get_available_variations();
print_r($product_variations);
```

This can be found in the class-wc-product-variable.php

So basically if you look around on that page you can find a bunch of useful functions.

Here is something i put together.

```
 $product_children = $product_variations->get_children();

 $child_variations = array();

 foreach ($product_children as $child){

 $child_variations[] = $product_variations->get_available_variation($child);

 }

 print_r($child_variations);
```

Answer (score 4):

I only wanted to publish one of the variation attributes rather than all of them; contributing this code in case it's helpful to anyone else.

get_variation_attributes() gets all the attributes

wc_get_formatted_variation() returns a formatted version of the array it's handed

```
$attributes =  $productVariation->get_variation_attributes() ;
if ( $attributes [ 'attribute_pa_colour' ] ) {
    $colour = [ 'attribute_pa_colour' => $attributes [ 'attribute_pa_colour'] ];
    echo wc_get_formatted_variation ( $colour );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I do it is by using "get_post_meta":

```
echo get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_name_field', true);
```

Hopes this helps someone.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the lowercased-version.

Answer (score 0):

I used *wp_get_post_terms* to get correct variance attributes.

```
    global $product;
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $var = [];
    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        $var[] = $variation['attributes'];
    }
    var_dump($var);
    //xxx to get attribute values with correct lower-upper-mixed-case
    foreach ($var as $key => $arr) {
      foreach ($arr as $orig_code => $lowercase_value) {
        $terms_arr = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, str_replace('attribute_','',$orig_code), array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        foreach ($terms_arr as $term) {
            if (strtolower($term) == $lowercase_value) {
                $var[$key][$orig_code] = $term;
                break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
    var_dump($var);
```

The results:

Before hard code

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute_pa_width' => string 'none' (length=4)
      'attribute_pa_code' => string 'valancese' (length=9)
```

After hard code:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute_pa_width' => string 'None' (length=4)
      'attribute_pa_code' => string 'ValanceSe' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this ...here is my solution.  It handles multiple attributes and all the variations.  You just have to know the attribute slug.

```
 $items  = $order->get_items();     
 foreach( $items as $item_id => $product ) 
 {  
 $ProductName = $product->get_name();        /

 if($product->is_type( 'simple' ))
   $CoreProductName = $ProductName;             // No variance   
 else
   {
   list($CoreProductName, $ThrowAway) = explode(" - ",$ProductName, 2); 

   $variation_id       = $product['variation_id'];
   $variation          = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
   $attributes         = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
   $SelectedAttribute1 = $attributes['attribute_YOUR_SLUG1_PER_PRODUCT'];
   $SelectedAttribute2 = $attributes['attribute_YOUR_SLUG2_PER_PRODUCT'];
  }
 }
```